# Error: gradle Task : "publish" uses the output of task ':jar" without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, maven-publish

I am using gradle 7.x.x and now facing an issue while running gitlab pipeline and during build stage.

Error:
gradle Task : "publish" uses the output of task ':jar" without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency.

Can anyone please help me with the solution ? Thanks :)

I tried enclosing puublishing block inside afterEvaluate block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to fix. You did not say whether you are using the Groovy or Kotlin DSL, so I will just give the Kotlin version. Add this to your `build.gradle.kts`.

```kotlin
tasks.named("publish") {
    dependsOn(tasks.named("jar"))
}
```

If you are using the Groovy DSL, refer to the DSL reference for examples of using the Groovy version:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/index.html

An important thing to understand is the first object in scope in a Gradle file is the `Project` class. Meaning that if you are not in another nested scope, and you type `tasks` at the beginning of the line, like above, this is referring to `Project.getTasks()`.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response. When I tried this solution it says task with name "publish" not found in root project. Though I have the task with this name.

I searched all tasks using ./gradlew tasks

Comment: If you do not have publishing defined in the root project, then add this in the Gradle file of the subproject where you have publishing defined.